# how to disable share button when user click share and enable it after 3 hours

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, onclick

I want to disable fb share button  after user click share for 3 hours and re enable again in php or javascript.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=358904180877188&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button"></div>
```

Comment: You realize you can not touch the button from your code. You could only not allow it to render...

Comment: why would you disable it? always let the user decide, maybe he wants to share on some different channels? it´s a very bad idea to disable the share function for 3 hours...

Comment: he gain a point for every share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify a callback in your FaceBook share code that sets a cookie that expires in 3 hours. Then in your view code (JS or PHP), only show the button (or execute the associated JS code) if that cookie's not present.